# Expand div with slideToggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have HTML like that :

```
<div id='hidden-section'>
  content is hidden
</div>
<div id='mainleft-content'>
  content is visible
</div>

<div id="expand-hidden">Button Expand + </div>
```

I use slideToggle to expand/collapse like code below, but it is not working :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hidden-section").hide();
    $("#expand-hidden").click(function(){
        $("#hidden-section").slideToggle();
            if($("#mainleft-content").is(":hidden")) {
                $("#mainleft-content").visible();
            }
            else{
                $("#mainleft-content").hide();
                }
    });

});
```

I want : when I click on `Button Expand` the hidden content(`hidden-section`) is visible and `mainleft-content` is hidden. when I click again, the 'hidden-section' is hidden and `mainleft-content` is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `visible()` function for jQuery you probably need `show()`

*Change*

```
$("#mainleft-content").visible();
```

*To*

```
  $("#mainleft-content").show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Same as [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/), you can use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to switch the display of an element. There is no need to use a `if` condition

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hidden-section").hide();
    $("#expand-hidden").click(function () {
        $("#hidden-section").stop(true, true).slideToggle();
        $("#mainleft-content").toggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vXJNT/)